# How can I reach the chests in the Iron Keep without dying?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I am of course referring to those chests that are on the magma stones and the item right below the stairs when you enter the Iron Keep area. I have tried using Flash Sweat Pyromancy combined with Fire resistance items, Lifegems and getting wet with the vases that contain water in order to survive, but I always seem to lose life too fast. Is there any effective way to reach those chests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you enter the front door guarded by two Alonne Knights after the bridge, immediately head right and then left, up a set of stairs. Another Alonne Knight will be there, kill him and you will see some vases. Rolling into these vases will give you immense fire resistance. The vases, in combination with Flash Sweat and Orange Burrs and Radiant (or better!) Lifegems and as much health points as you can and preferably the Smelter's Demon armour set will net you the items.

Comment: And what should I use with the one right below the entrance to the Smelter Demon room?

Comment: It is possible to drop down beside it from the ledge, make sure you use the cat ring (you may die but at least you get the loot, as we all know, it's all about the loot)

Comment: What I mean is that there're no vases anywhere near, what should I use beside the obvious combo of items (as I see that's the key point to resisting long enough to open the chests and take the loot)?

Comment: Face the Smelter Demon entrance, turn 180. Run forward until you see a gap in the floor, jump over it. Look to your right and you will see a broken staircase (where the Dull Ember is), jump over and head through the doorway, up the stairs, kill the Alonne Captain and use a Pharros Lockstone. This creates a pool of water for you to roll in, it has the same effect as the vases.

Comment: Excelent, that completely answers the question, I'll mark it now as accepted :)